# Include statement: can't find SDL/SDL.h file

Tags: c++, xcode

My understanding is that when I build a C++ project in xcode and I have an include line in one of my C files in [angle-bracket form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36k2cdd4.aspx) then the C++ compiler that works with xcode looks in `/System/Library/Frameworks/` to find the file. I think that because of this answer: [when I use the line #include <OpenGL/gl.h> in my xcode project, where does it look for the gl.h file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19147773/when-i-use-the-line-include-opengl-gl-h-in-my-xcode-project-where-does-it-lo)

I have an SDL.h file at `/System/Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework/headers/SDL.h` (I downloaded  the folder SDL.framework and copied it to that location with the command `sudo cp -r /Volumes/SDL/SDL.framework System/Library/Frameworks`)

But my include statement in one of the files in my xcode project still gives this error:

```
#include <SDL/SDL.h> //throws file not found
```

Did I properly install the SDL framework? Why doesn't xcode see it?

Comment: why is it not `#include <SDL.h>`

Comment: Does the directory `headers` need to be capitalized as `Headers`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Under your projects **Build Settings**, do a search for "search".  Add a header search path to the  SDL directory **/System/Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework/headers**

Should be able to just do this after:

```
#include <SDL.h>
```

Hope that works for you.

You can also check out this link:
 http://meandmark.com/blog/2012/01/using-sdl-with-xcode-4/

It's for Xcode 4, but it looks like all the pieces are there.