# Xcode can't find the header path after build

Tags: c++, xcode11

I have created a project in Xcode with SDL2.framework and SDL.h. First build was successful but then I got the error:

> *Did not find header 'SDL.h' in framework 'SDL2'
>
> (loaded from
> /Users/silmarinor/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/2D_GameEngine_from_Youtube-azumshzwimbsrrbrcuzbsccudlci/Build/Products/Debug').*

The actual path to SDL2.framework is `/usr/local/Library/sdl2` and it is added to the *Search Paths*, *Frameworks and Libraries*.

How to be able to build the project again without creating new?

Comment: Try adding the framework to target dependencies  https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Xok0.png

Comment: I was not able to find Target Dependencies but there are Dependencies in Build Phases

Comment: Anyway, I can't add there sdl2.framework

Comment: It works know after certain changes!

Answer (score 0):

1. I've created a new project
2. I've changed the direction of SDL2.framework to ***/Library/Frameworks***
3. I've added the SDL2.framework to *Frameworks and Libraries*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150739/include-statement-cant-find-sdl-sdl-h-file